# Is there a way in Java to notify another thread that you've made a blocking call, after the latter has actually blocked?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, blocking

Say that `blockAndDoSomeLongWork()` is a method that blocks. Usually, we'd perform it on another thread:

```java
someExecutorService.execute(() -> {
    blockAndDoSomeLongWork();
});
```

Question is: is there a way to notify a thread that i've called `blockAndDoSomeLongWork()` after the fact so that i will be absolutely sure that the other thread won't do anything before `blockAndDoSomeLongWork()` has been called? If i simply wake up the other thread via call in the lambda's body that immediately precedes `blockAndDoSomeLongWork()`, this makes it possible for the other thread to execute an action before `blockAndDoSomeLongWork()` was called, which is something i want to avoid.

Comment: Have you looked into `synchronized()`? Thus: `synchronized(BlockingObjectInstance) {/* do work in this thread */}`

Comment: A thread that is blocked will not be doing any work.  If you want to make sure two threads don't interfere with each other Google for "Java mutex".  If you want to know how to design for multithreading/parallelism, well that's a very broad subject.  You'd first want to make sure you have a handle on the basics though (like mutex).

Comment: @markspace - It appears the OP is attempting to delay execution of a different thread until the blocking thread releases rather than running in parallel. A mutex is the wrong tool for that job.

Comment: A Semaphore or a CountdownLatch is appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

Use a semaphore:

```
Semaphore sema = new Semaphore(0);
```

This thread:

```
someExecutorService.execute(() -> {
    blockAndDoSomeLongWork();
    sema.release();
});
```

Other thread:

```
sema.acquire();
// when we get here, the 'long work' has completed
```

This assumes there is exactly one 'other' thread, and rather more subtly, assumes that the 'long work' is a one-time thing.  Otherwise you might need two-way interlocking.

Comment: I want to block, but notify the other thread at the same time. I don't want to wait for `blockAndDoSomeLongWork()` to finish. So `sema.release()` should be called before `blockAndDoSomeWork()` in a way that the other thread has not had any change to do any work, before `blockAndDoSomeLongWork()` was called and blocked. Right now, i call `sema.release()` on yet another thread and hope for the best. Is there a better way?

Comment: You need to come up with a solution that signals "ok to proceed" at the point at which is is ok to proceed, whether that  signal is by semaphore or anything else.  If the point is not reached until blockAndDoSomeLongWork has at least made some progress, then the signal has to come from within blockAndDoSomeLongWork itself, since only it knows when it has done "some" work.

Comment: Other than that, you can come up with a duct-tape solution that sort-of appears to work, by signalling the semaphore before blockAndDoSomeLongWork starts, and then have the 'other' thread wait a little after acquiring the semaphore.  "Wait a little" could be as crude as sleeping an appropriate time (which is pretty hacky) or by examining whatever there is that determines that "some work" has happened.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is impossible. It's hard to imagine why you would ever need it.

Let's say there was a notifyOtherThreadAndBlock() call.

This call would notify the other thread and then block.

But, this call has code in it. It notifies the other thread, then it blocks. What if your thread gets stopped after the notifying, and before the blocking? This is the same problem you already had. Putting it into a function didn't solve anything.

Now, it *is* *theoretically* possible. Maybe the operating system could have a function that says "hey, next time I block, please notify this other thread for me." But operating systems don't have that function. Why not? Because it's useless. You're supposed to just notify the other thread before you start blocking, because it doesn't make any difference anyway.

If it does make a difference, then your code is doing something wrong, and you should explain your situation better, so we can explain how to make it so you *can* notify before blocking.

Comment: It is for testing purposes, that is why it seems so contrived. It manually wires a server and a client in the test. Server has to basically say, paraphrasing your example - "hey, i am ready to receive your data without missing a byte and do the work, send away."

Comment: @hrs So what happens if the client sends the data before the server says it's ready? Then the operating system queues it up and the server receives it anyway. So what's the problem?